# Hadoop on archlinux | dfs cannot start | ssh port 22 connection refused

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh

i just can't find any answers for this problem:

> `[hadoop@evghost ~]$ start-dfs.sh
>   15/10/21 21:59:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
>   Starting namenodes on []
>   evghost: ssh: connect to host evghost port 22: Connection refused
>   evghost: ssh: connect to host evghost port 22: Connection refused
>   Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>   Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.
>   15/10/21 21:59:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

Does somebody know any solution?

Comment: Namenode can't connect datanode. try to connect with with ssh from nn to dn.  maybe network disable or over loading.

Comment: okey, i'll try. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should enable daemon sshd to connect and post

> export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS
>   -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"

in .bashrc

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question? Did it answer it? It so "accept" it so others can see how the problem was solved.

Comment: I can do it tomorrow. Some restriction.